# How to change socket bind port of program? without source code

Tags: windows, sockets, windbg

**PROBLEM:**

I have a program **dummy.exe** on windows. 
this program will bind to **UDP port 5060**, after started.
but another program also want to bind port 5060.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:**

1. using windbg to start dummy.exe, and set breakpoint on ws2_32!bind
2. when the breakpoint hit, i changed the parameter (port value) with command **ew**
3. this dummy.exe will bind to the new port, and worked well.

**QUESTION:**

- How can i do that easily?  write a
  simple windows debugger?
- Maybe i can hacking or modify the
  dummy.exe file, but how to do that?
- what's your way to achieve this?

**thanks**

**EDIT1:**

Thanks very much @Cody Gray and @cdhowie

1. This software do not provide functionality to change port.
2. I need use this software to communicate with others who also use this software.
3. For 'simple' debugger, i mean call CreateProcess with flag 
   DEBUG_PROCESS to start dummy.exe, and WaitForDebugEvent, then hook the ws2_32!bind
   function to modify the port parameter, but i do not sure wheather it works
4. i used UltraEdit to find the value 0x13C4 (5060), but after i changed the value,
   it does not works :(  , any suggestion?

Comment: Does the software provide functionality to change the port that it listens on from the default? If not, I highly recommend either finding a new program to use or writing your own utility. Attaching a debugger to software each time you want to use it is hardly a plan. And what in the world would a "simple" Windows debugger look like? Why would that be preferable?

Comment: Using a hex editor to adjust the value might be a possible plan, if the program's license agreement permits this activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options here. First, along the lines of what you already mentioned, you can patch the parameters to the `bind()` call at runtime, using hooking. Popular libraries to do that are [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) or [madCodeHook](http://madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm), or example. This would definitely work, I used to do that myself.

The second option you also already mentioned, although I'd suggest not using a hex editor to simply search for those values, there might be multiple occurrences in the file and using only a hex editor, it might be hard to find the right one. What you can do, however, is use a debugger that is able to write a modified image back to disk. [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) offers a very comfortable way to do that.

I'd suggest going for the hooking method though, that way, you can inject code around the binding to read the port from a configuration file, or similar in order to avoid the need to patch the executable or recompile your code time and again.

Comment: thanks for your help, the DetourCreateProcessWithDll API is what i need. :)